# Induction on the size of the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Show that every non-empty finite set of real numbers has a maximum. (Hint: induction on the size of set).

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. I'm familiar with induction, but I don't know where I am supposed to apply it.

Right now, I have:

$P(n)$ : Every set $S = \{a_1, ... , a_n\}$ has a maximum.

$P(n+1)$ : Every set $S = \{a_1, ..., a_n, a_{n+1}\}$ has a maximum.

This doesn't really seem like a rigorous argument, nor do I think it proves the claim. I think I am supposed to do something with the cardinality of  set, but we haven't covered it in this course. I remember this property (of power sets, I believe) from a previous course:

$$|2^S| = 2^{|S|}.$$

Any ideas on which direction I should head in?

Comment: "induction on the size of set" means you should first prove it for sets with 1 element, then assuming it holds for sets with $\leq n$ elements prove it for sets with $n+1$ elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Assume that every set of $n$ natural numbers has a maximum, and let $A$ be a set of $n+1$ natural numbers. Let $a$ be any element of $A$; then $A\setminus\{a\}$ has $n$ elements, so it has a maximum element $m$. Now compare $a$ and $m$.

Comment: That's more of a proof than a hint. ;-)

Comment: @nomen: Might be; depending on the student it could be anything from quite inadequate to gross overkill!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott So since a is any element of A and A has a maximum element m, then a < m? And therefore, every set of n natural numbers has a maximum?

Comment: @Javier: No, not at all: $a$ is a *particular* element of $A$. It just doesn’t matter which one you choose. If it helps you to think about it, let $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1}\}$, and take $a=a_{n+1}$. Then $A\setminus\{a\}=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ is a set of $n$ elements, so by the induction hypothesis it has a maximum element $m$. We have no idea whether $a_{n+1}$ is less than $m$ or greater than $m$: it’s not a member of the $n$-element set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ whose maximum is $m$. But it doesn’t matter whether $m<a_{n+1}$ or $m>a_{n+1}$: either way, you should be able to say why $A$ ...

Comment: ... has a maximum element.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow. How has this proved that a set with n elements has a maximum? And what is the point of doing induction on the size of the set if we are only going to remove the "inducted" element after the induction step?

Comment: @Javier: It’s not intended to prove that a set with $n$ elements has a maximum element: that’s the induction hypothesis, and we’re trying to use it to prove that every set with $n+1$ elements has a maximum element. So we take a set $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1}\}$ with $n+1$ elements, use the induction hypothesis to say that the subset $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ has a maximum element (which we’re calling $m$), and use that to explain why $A$ itself must have a maximum element. If you know that $m$ is the largest of the numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, what are the only two numbers that could be the max. of $A$?

Comment: @Brian Oh, I see now. The only two numbers that could be the max of A are either m itself or a_n+1. Thanks!

Comment: @Javier: There you go. You’re welcome!